# How can I update my Gnome Extension?

Tags: gnome3

I have [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/844/maximus-two/), which I created as a spin off of [this one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) and is basically the same, it just removes the adding of buttons to the panel (I did this to make it easier to use on a computer with a small screen).

I have created a few updates for it, but I cannot work out how to upload them.

Is there a place I can find documentation to do this ([here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(that was easy)

Updating the version number properly and then uploading the zip file [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/upload/) worked.